# Android: Cannot paste images to drawable-hdpi folder in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, android-drawable

I am trying to paste a few images to drawable-hdpi folder of eclipse, directly by ctrl-c and ctrl-v. So far it was working. But now suddenly eclipse is giving an error

> cannot paste the clipboard contents into the selected elements

I tried pasting directly into my project folder. I also tried cleaning the project and closing the eclipse. It still gives the same error.

Error is not only with the current project but with the other projects too. Cannot paste the images in any project's drawable folder.

Can somebody tell me what the problem is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the name of drawable? It may possible that name of file doesn't match will android drawable files policy, but not 100% sure.

Comment: it is eclipse's drawable-hdpi

Comment: Just as an idea. Don't use Eclipse to copy the files. Copy them with our file browser. After you are done goto Eclipse, click at the project's root and press F5.

Comment: i think your copying the images directly from the zip/rar file.. if so , please extract that zip/rar file then copy and paste the images it will work...

Comment: @SilentKiller: Thank u. It worked suddenly. However even this din't work before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Eclipse to copy files. Copy them using file browser. After you are done go to Eclipse,

1. Select project's root and press F5 

   **Or**
2. Right click on project root and click on refresh

Which will refresh your Project folder and load all the files and folder in your project